# Finding random k points at least d apart in 3D confined space

Tags: algorithm, random

For my simulation purposes, I want to generate a randomly distributed k number of spheres (having the same radii) in a confined 3D space (inside a rectangle) where k is in order of 1000. Those spheres should not impinge on one another.

So, I want to generate random k points in a 3D space at least d distance away from one another; considering the number of points and the frequency at which I need those points for simulation, I don't want to apply brute force; I'm looking for some efficient algorithms achieving this.

Comment: Can you please give more context and tell you about what is E3?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I mean in 1000, I've edited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generate 3-d random points with minimum distance between each of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780328/generate-3-d-random-points-with-minimum-distance-between-each-of-them)

Comment: What you're asking appears not to be possible in general.

Comment: @mnulb while writing I realised that I didn't have a good feeling for what you were after, adding details to the question would help giving a more appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

How about just starting with some regular tessellation of the space (i.e. some [primitive 3d lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice)) and putting a single point somewhere in each tile?  You'd then only need to check a small number of neighboring tiles for proximity.

To get a more statistically uniform, i.e. less regular, set of points, you could:

- perturb points in space
- generate an overly dense lattice and reject some points
- "warp" the space so that the lattice was more dense in certain areas

You could perturb the points sequentially, giving you a monte-carlo chain over their coordinates, and potentially saving work elsewhere.  Presumably you could tailor this so that the equilibrium distribution was what you wanted.